# Java Spring MVC Controller is not redirecting modelandview

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

An AJAX-call is done to the Controller:

```
$.ajax({
      cache : false,
      type : "POST",
      url : url,
      data : {
        //some data
      }
```

That call is successfully interpreted by the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/checkIfRatedOverall")
public ModelAndView checkIfRatedOverall(@ReqestParam.......)
```

But when i return the **ModelAndView** nothing happens!
The view stays the same and the browser does not display `xxx.jsp`

```
return new ModelAndView("xxx"); //NOTHING HAPPENS
```

LOG:

```
JstlView:166 - Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/views/xxx.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'xxx'

DispatcherServlet:1251 - Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'xxx'

DispatcherServlet:1000 - Successfully completed request
```

Comment: have you added the view resolvers?

Comment: yes i did: 
<beans:bean
 class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
  <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
 </beans:bean>

Comment: what is your controller mapping and the url that you use to invoke?

Comment: AJAX-URL: 'http://localhost:8080/web/checkIfRatedOverall'
CONTROLLER: @RequestMapping(value = "/checkIfRatedOverall")

Comment: can you update your checkIfRatedOverall method, and it seems you neet to pass a request param as well

Comment: there are request parameter but why do you need them?
this method returns successfully - without errors -> problem is only that the view does not change?

Comment: typically ajax request does not return whole html document as you does with with jsp now. usaually it is some json data. I am not quite sure I how do you respond on response. and what exactly you are trying to achieve

Comment: _"The view stays the same "_ That is the expected result when you make an AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

your internal view resolver should be like this

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
```

Comment: it looks exactly like this. unfortunately this is not the problem.

Comment: how do you invoke the controller? url?

Comment: yes, i do invoke the controller with url (see ajax url)

Comment: @QuickSort ok. since you are making this as ajax call, how do you respond on response arrival (remember you are returning jsp page - not json data),

Answer (score 0):

Check ajax documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

```
$.ajax({ ...}).done(
      function( html ) {
           $( "#results" ).append( html );
      });
```

What you do with the ajax response? From what I see you are doing nothing with server response.

Comment: i do not need an ajax response - so there is no need for a response; I only want the controller to show me a different view -> **return new ModelAndView("view")**. But the new view is not shown in the browser, it stays on the old view.

Comment: Then you don't need to make an ajax call. You can simply use a link ( <a href=) or a form.

Comment: I considered this option, but for some reasons i want to use an AJAX-call. And I want to understand the problem here.

Comment: Ok, if you want to use AJAX try to understand what AJAX does. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)

Comment: Finally I got it. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Use @ResponseBody Attribute and return JSON object instead of model view

```
@RequestMapping(value = "checkIfRatedOverall", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String checkIfRatedOverall(@ReqestParam.......)
{
    return jsonStr://return json string
}
```

In jquery parse the string with JSON.parse(data)

```
$.ajax({
    cache : false,
    type : "POST",
    url : url,
    data : {
        //some data
    },
    success : function(data) {
        JSON.parse(data);
    }
});
```